# first n digits of an exponentiation

Tags: c++, c, math, exponentiation

How do i determine the first n digits of an exponentiation (a<sup>b</sup>).

```
eg: for a = 12, b = 13 & n = 4, the first 4 digits are 1069.
```

Comment: I see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635183/fast-exponentiation-when-only-first-k-digits-are-required but i don't get the clear picture. Cld someone elaborate briefly.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better on math.stackexchange? I don't see a programming question here.

Comment: @Mark B: Considering the languages it was tagged in, and the fact that `snprintf` or the C++ equivalent is likely one possible implementation that does not require writing the algorithm yourself, I think this question is completely appropriate on SO.

Comment: @R The question didn't state that you were allowed to restrict yourself to the set of values representable by a `double` and I assumed they could be arbitrary. Developing the appropriate algorithm to generate just the first `n` digits would be more appropriate for math.stackexchange.

Comment: I've asked similarly mathematical questions here from a programming standpoint before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215235/how-do-you-print-the-exact-value-of-a-floating-point-number) and never had anyone question whether it's off-topic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Calculate a<sup>b</sup> by the following iterations:

*a<sub>1</sub> = a<sup>1</sup>*,
*a<sub>2</sub> = a<sup>2</sup>*,
*...*
*a<sub>i</sub> = a<sup>i</sup>*,
*...*
*a<sub>b</sub> = a<sup>b</sup>*

You have *a<sub>i+1</sub> = a<sub>i</sub>×a*. Calcluate each *a<sub>i</sub>* not exactly. The thing is that the relative error of *a<sup>b</sup>* is less than *n* times relative error of *a*.
You want to get final relative error  less than *10<sup>-n</sup>*. Thus relative error on each step may be [image: forumula]. Remove last digits at each step.

For example, *a=2*, *b=16*, *n=1*. Final relative error is *10<sup>-n</sup> = 0.1*. Relative error on each step is *0.1/16 > 0.001*. Thus 3 digits is important on each step. If n = 2, you must save 4 digits. Common rule: save [*n+log<sub>10</sub> b*] digits at each step.

2 (1), 4 (2), 8 (3), 16 (4), 32 (5), 64 (6), 128 (7), 256 (8), 512 (9), 1024 (10) → 102,
204 (11), 408 (12), 816 (13), 1632 (14) → 163, 326 (15), 652 (16).

Answer: 6.

This algorithm has a compexity of *O(b)*. But it is easy to change it to get *O(log b)*

Comment: How relative error on each step is (10^(-n))/b, means how to derive it? Can you please explain?

Answer (score 6):

Another solution, using log10:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
       int a = 12;
       int b = 13;
       int n = 4;
       double x, y;

       x = b * log10(a);
       y = floor(pow(10, x - floor(x) + n - 1));
       printf("Result: %d\n", (int)y);

       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

n=9 k=3 n^n=387420489 and answer should be 387

[image]

this is the same thing, what @RC as done in his code.
Thank you @RC i just showed the mathematic representation your code.

Answer (score 1):

For this case - with magic numbers 12,13,4 in place:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

double a = 12;
int b = 13;
double result = std::pow(a,b);

std::stringstream strVal;
strVal.setf( ios::fixed, ios::floatfield );
strVal << result;
std::string output(strVal.str().substr(0,4));
```

output = "1069"

```
std::stringstream intStr(output);
int intVal;
intStr >> intVal;
```

intVal = 1069

EDIT: 
This should work for any combination where result does not overflow `double`.

Comment: Is this correct even for huge numbers as long as the result does not overflow `double`? I suspect so, but it would be worth discussing as part of a complete answer.

Comment: @R.. - good point, edited to use `long double` and added comment

Comment: `long double` is likely the same as `double` on Windows. Some analysis of whether the code will be subject to floating point imprecision would be better than just throwing bigger types at it to sweep the issue under the rug.

Comment: @R.. - it's as accurate as runtime library's pow function isn't it? Am I missing your point?

Comment: Unless your system's floating point to decimal conversion is better than any specification requires, it will fail with `n>DECIMAL_DIG`, even if `pow(a,b)` is exactly representable (which will always be the case if `a` is a power of 2). Whether there are other failure cases, I'm not sure. I think it's fine as long as `n` is significantly smaller than `DECIMAL_DIG`.

Comment: @R.. - thanks - on Windows you can optionally use SSE2 to support pow.  Not sure if that affects the accuracy, or just performance.

Comment: Sure. BTW, "What are the first 100 digits of 2^10000?" is a perfectly reasonable question where the `pow(2,10000)` would work (for 80-bit or higher `long double`) but where the standard library might not be able to print 100 accurate decimal digits. For what it's worth, glibc will do it correctly and MSVCRT will not.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way programatically to do this is to use a stringstream to convert the result of the exponentation to a string and then take the n most significant (i.e. left) characters.

if you want a way without strings then this will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double nDigExp( double a, double b, int n )
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss.setf( ios::fixed, ios::floatfield );
    ss << pow(a,b);
    double ret;
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i) ret = (10 * ret) + (ss.get() - '0'); // Yeuch!!
    return ret;
}

int main( )
{
    double result = nDigExp( 12, 13, 4 );

    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But it's hardly the most elegent code. I'm sure you can improve it.