# First N digits of a long number in constant-time?

Tags: algorithm, clojure, numbers

In a Project Euler problem I need to deal with numbers that can have hundreds of digits. And I need to perform some calculation on the first 9 digits.

My question is: what is the fastest possible way to determine the first N digits of a 100-digit integer? Last N digits are easy with modulo/remainder. For the first digits I can apply modulo 100 times to get digit by digit, or I can convert the number to String and truncate, but they all are linear time. Is there a better way?

Comment: most project Euler solutions have "a ha!" solutions as well as 'brute force'...Also, your question is not programming related

Comment: why converting the number to String and doing str[i] is linear ?

Comment: @Mitch: How exactly is this question "not programming related"?

Comment: nice question from someone with ~10k. Can you provide more details: how integer is represented and how you want to use those 9 digits? Btw, seems that you are on the wrong way with your current solution is you require this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can count number of digits with this function:

```
(defn dec-digit-count [n]
  (inc (if (zero? n) 0
  (long (Math/floor (Math/log10 n))))))
```

Now we know how many digits are there, and we want to leave only first 9. What we have to is divide the number with 10^(digits-9) or in Clojure:

```
(defn first-digits [number digits]
  (unchecked-divide number (int (Math/pow 10 digits))))
```

And call it like: `(first-digits your-number 9)` and I think it's in constant time. I'm only not sure about `log10` implementation. But, it's sure a lot faster that a modulo/loop solution.

Also, there's an even easier solution. You can simply copy&paste first 9 digits from the number.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I haven't thought about log10. So obvious once you found it. :-)

Comment: @Konrad: To quote Mitch Wheat: "A-ha!" :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use not a long number, but tupple of two numbers: [first-digits, last-digits]. Perform operations on both of them, each time truncating to the required length (twice of the condition, 9 your case) the first at the right and the second at the left. 
Like

```
222000333 * 666000555
147|852344988184|815

222111333 * 666111555
147|950925407752|815
```

so you can do only two small calculations: 222 * 666 = 147[852] and 333 * 555 = [184]815

But the comment about "a ha" solution is the most relevant for Project Euler :)

Comment: Thanks, indeed this turned out to be the most popular and easiest solution to that problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long N = 7812938291232L;
        System.out.println(N / (int) (Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(N)) - 8)));
        N = 1234567890;
        System.out.println(N / (int) (Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(N)) - 8)));
        N = 1000000000;
        System.out.println(N / (int) (Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(N)) - 8)));
    }
}
```

yields

```
781293829
123456789
100000000
```

Answer (score 0):

It may helps you [first n digits of an exponentiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873298/first-n-digits-of-an-exponentiation)

and the answer of from this question

> This algorithm has a compexity of O(b). But it is easy to change it to get O(log b)