# Is there any quick way to determine first k digits on n^n

Tags: algorithm, numerical-methods

I am writing a program where I need to know only the first k (k can be anywhere between 1-5) numbers of another big number which can be represented as n^n where n is a very large number.

Currently I am actually calculating n^n and then parsing it as a string. I wonder if there is a better more  fast method exists.

Comment: Which digit is the "first"? The ones digit?

Comment: Can u pls explain with an example?

Comment: Yes.  Look into approximations for this...

Comment: There is an algorithm for any exponentiation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873298/first-n-digits-of-an-exponentiation

Comment: Example n=4 k=1, then answer is 2,6 (since 4^4=256)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two possibilities.

If you want the first k leading digits (as in: the leading digit of 12345 is 1), then you can use the fact that

```
n^n = 10^(n*Log10(n))
```

so you compute the fractional part `f` of `n*Log10(n)`, and then the first k digits of `10^f` will be your result. This works for numbers up to about 10^10 before round-off errors start kicking in if you use double precision. For example, for `n = 2^20`, `f = 0.57466709...`, `10^f = 3.755494...` so your first 5 digits are 37554. For `n = 4`, `f = 0.4082...`, `10^f = 2.56` so your first digit is 2.

If you want the first k trailing digits (as in: the trailing digit of 12345 is 5), then you can use modular arithmetic. I would use the squaring trick:

```
factor = n mod 10^k
result = 1
while (n != 0) 
    if (n is odd) then result = (result * factor) mod 10^k
    factor = (factor * factor) mod 10^k
    n >>= 1
```

Taking n=2^20 as an example again, we find that `result = 88576`. For n=4, we have `factor = 1, 4, 6` and `result = 1, 1, 6` so the answer is 6.

Comment: For calculating first k leading digits, this is more clear what it said.
http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/15398/first-k-digits-of-nn

Answer (score 3):

if you mean the least significant or rightmost digits, this can be done with modular multiplication. It's O(N) complexity and doesn't require any special bignum data types.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

//returns ((base ^ exponent) % mod)
int modularExponentiation(int base, int exponent, int mod){
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < exponent; i++){
        result = (result * base) % mod;
    }
    return result;
}

int firstKDigitsOfNToThePowerOfN(int k, int n){
    return modularExponentiation(n, n, pow(10, k));
}

int main(){
    int n = 11;
    int result = firstKDigitsOfNToThePowerOfN(3, n);
    printf("%d", result); 
}
```

This will print 611, the first three digits of 11^11 = 285311670611.

This implementation is suitable for values of N less than sqrt(INT_MAX), which will vary but on my machine and language it's over 46,000.

Furthermore, if it so happens that your INT_MAX is less than (10^k)^2, you can change modularExponentiation to handle any N that can fit in an int:

```
int modularExponentiation(int base, int exponent, int mod){
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < exponent; i++){
        result = (result * (base % mod)) % mod; //doesn't overflow as long as mod * mod < INT_MAX
    }
    return result;
}
```

if O(n) time is insufficient for you, we can take advantage of the property of exponentiation that A^(2*C) = (A^C)^2, and get logarithmic efficiency.

```
//returns ((base ^ exponent) % mod)
int modularExponentiation(int base, int exponent, int mod){
    if (exponent == 0){return 1;}
    if (exponent == 1){return base % mod;}
    if (exponent % 2 == 1){
        return ((base % mod) * modularExponentiation(base, exponent-1, mod)) % mod;
    }
    else{
        int newBase = modularExponentiation(base, exponent / 2, mod);
        return (newBase * newBase) % mod;
    }
}
```

Comment: no offense, but your exponentiation algorithm is a little inefficient.. it can go down to O(log(exp)) from the O(exp) it is now. Also, `pow` returns floats/doubles, might as well use your own modexp for it right? (just set the mod to 1<<30 or such)

Comment: @harold, you're right, we can do better than O(N). It took me a while to remember that A^(2C) = (A^C)^2, which gives us a nice shortcut.

Comment: yup, looks better now, you can also make it a simple loop by the way (as in Jeffrey's answer)