# Calculating the first and last k digits in n^n

Tags: java, c, algorithm, math

I need to print the first `k` digits and the last `k` digits in

---

`n^n (n to the power of n, where n is an integer)`
For example :

---

```
Input       Output

n k         First k digits       Last k digits

4 2    -->  25                   56
9 3    -->  387                  489
```

---

I sense that it requires some clever mathematics, however I am unable to think of anything as such. Please suggest a way to approach the problem.

Comment: This is your homework. You should consider doing the work by yourself.

Comment: Also i would question the constraints first. Is n^n big enough not to be computable outright that you have to find another clever way?

Comment: Actually, this is no homework. I was just trying to solve some problems for fun. But I got stuck in it. That's why I asked, and that too just how to approach it.

Comment: n^n would cause an overflow in case of large integer values.

Comment: You tagged your question with "homework". But good try though ;-)

Comment: Consider that to some, 'homework' is work you do at home. Nothing more... to most of us it is of course school work.

Comment: This could have been interesting only if you had asked for the MIDDLE k digits of n^n, for n large enough.

Comment: The question seems to be taken from [here](http://www.codechef.com/problems/MARCHA4) I am not sure if such questions should be (or are being) encouraged.

Comment: @Shagun: Well.. I guess people like me are not so smart.. THey want to learn which may involve asking about how to program and they may use sites like these to ask problems.. Please feel free to ignore us !

Comment: No offence meant mate. All I mean is such questions should either be on [forums](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/15398/first-k-digits-of-nn) dedicated to such questions specifically or atleast the context of such problems should be given clearly so that others can learn too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last k digits are easy, you just need to calculate it `modulo 10^k`. To do this, after every multiplication, just apply the modulo, ie. `intermediate_result %= 10^k`.

Of course, you will need to calculate `10^k` using some other method, because `^` does not mean power of in C or Java.

To find the first k digits, see [first n digits of an exponentiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873298/first-n-digits-of-an-exponentiation).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for their help. My final code is

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long int lastKdigits(long long n,int k)
{
long long i,res=1,div=pow(10,k);

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    res=(res*n)%div;
}

return res;
}

long int firstKdigits(long long n,int k)
{
   long double x, y;

   x = n*log10(n);
   y = floor(pow(10,x-floor(x) +k-1));
   return ((int)y);
}

int main()
{

long long n;
int k;

scanf("%lld %d",&n,&k);

printf("%ld\t",firstKdigits(n,k));
printf("%ld\n",lastKdigits(n,k));
}

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For last `k` digits it's pretty easy you just need to calculate `n^n (mod 10^k)` but I don't know any solution for the other k diggits!